# How to get PIDs using a mount point before removed by udev on plug out

Tags: c, linux, debian, udev

I want to know mechanism to get processes using any mount point before unmounted and remove by udev on removing the storage device in Debian OS.

When I skip remove directory in udev rule file it get a lot of processes including kernel etc.

I want to implement an alert message on screen if some one remove pen drive from system while uploading or downloading in the pen drive.

Please help me.

Comment: have you looked into the `/proc/` filesystem ?

Answer (score 1):

You may use `lsof` command. This command lists which process is using which file. output contains command, PID, USERID, file type, Device, side , file name etc. 
You may grep for mount point to find who is using your device.

**Syntax :**

```
#lsof  | grep <mount point>
```

OR

```
#lsof  <mount point>
```

Other option is to use `fuser` command. It displays process IDs which are using given file/dir

**Syntax :**

```
#fuser <mount point >
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am getting it by fuser. My question is how to handle it after removed by user.  In my system hot plugging is managed by udev rules. Its show  Specified filename /media/pen-drive does not exist.   Remove action is ACTION=="remove", ENV{dir_name}!="", RUN+="/bin/sh -c '/bin/fuser -m /media/%E{dir_name'", RUN+="/bin/umount -l /media/%E{dir_name}", RUN+="/bin/rmdir /media/%E{dir_name}"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply. I am getting it by fuser. My question is how to handle it after removed by user. In my system hot plugging is managed by udev rules. Its show Specified filename 
/media/pen-drive does not exist. Remove action is 
ACTION=="remove", ENV{dir_name}!="", RUN+="/bin/sh -c '/bin/fuser -m /media/%E{dir_name'", RUN+="/bin/umount -l /media/%E{dir_name}", RUN+="/bin/rmdir /media/%E{dir_name}"